# are fread and fwrite different in handling the internal buffer?

Tags: c, linux

I keep on reading that `fread()` and `fwrite()` are buffered library calls. In case of `fwrite()`, I understood that once we write to the file, it won't be written to the hard disk, it will fill the internal buffer and once the buffer is full, it will call `write()` system call to write the data actually to the file.

But I am not able to understand how this buffering works in case of `fread()`. Does buffered in case of `fread()` mean, once we call `fread()`, it will read more data than we originally asked and that extra data will be stored in buffer (so that when 2<sup>nd</sup> `fread()` occurs, it can directly give it from buffer instead of going to hard disk)?

And I have following queries also.

1. If `fread()` works as I mention above, then will first `fread()` call read the data that is   equal to the size of the internal buffer? If that is the case, if my `fread()` call ask for more bytes than internal buffer size, what will happen?
2. If `fread()` works as I mention above, that means at least one `read()` system call to kernel will happen for sure in case of `fread()`. But in case of `fwrite()`, if we only call `fwrite()` once during the program execution, we can't say for sure that `write()` system call be called. Is my understanding correct?
3. Will the internal buffer be maintained by OS?
4. Does `fclose()` flush the internal buffer?

Comment: I/O solutions vary but your post is on the write track.  1. Multiple calls to the low level I/O. 2. The low level I/O will be called on `fclose()`. 3. Yes 4. Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is buffering or caching at many different levels in a modern system.  This might be typical:

- C standard library
- OS kernel
- disk controller (esp. if using hardware RAID)
- disk drive

When you use `fread()`, it may request 8 KB or so if you asked for less.  This will be stored in user-space so there is no system call and context switch on the next sequential read.

The kernel may read ahead also; there are library functions to give it hints on how to do this for your particular application.  The OS cache could be gigabytes in size since it uses main memory.

The disk controller may read ahead too, and could have a cache size up to hundreds of megabytes on smallish systems.  It can't do as much in terms of read-ahead, because it doesn't know where the next logical block is for the current file (indeed it doesn't even know what file it is reading).

Finally, the disk drive itself has a cache, perhaps 16 MB or so.  Like the controller, it doesn't know what file it is reading.  For many years one disk block was 512 bytes, but it got a little larger (a few KB) recently with multi-terabyte disks.

When you call `fclose()`, it will probably deallocate the user-space buffer, but not the others.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct. And any buffered fwrite data will be flushed when the FILE* is closed. The buffered I/O is mostly transparent for I/O on regular files.

But for terminals and other character devices you may care.  Another instance where buffered I/O may be an issue is if you read from the file that one process is writing to from another process -- a common example is if a program writes text to a log file during operation, and the user runs a command like `tail -f program.log` to watch the content of the log file live.  If the writing process has buffering enabled and it doesn't explicitly flush the log file, it will make it difficult to monitor the log file.